# Always true conditions

Tags: python

I have the following Python script:

```
playerInput = ""
x = playerInput != "a";
y = playerInput != "b";
while x or y:
    playerInput = input();
```

The problem is both conditions are always true, no matter, what I write.

Comment: "The problem is both conditions are always true, no matter, what I write" - no, one of them can be false. You've required both of them to be false to stop the loop, though. Also, you never redo the tests.

Comment: What is the initial value of `playerInput` ?

Comment: "I still don't get how to use" is not a problem specification.  Your code fails to run, since `playerInput` is undefined at the first line.  I edited your posting to give it a value.

Comment: @Prune `playerInput` is very much so defined. It has a value of `""`.

Comment: @mypetition Yes ... after I edited the question ...

Comment: @Prune So it would seem...

Answer (score 3):

Both conditions are `True` because you set them that way before the loop (ostensibly you gave `playerInput` some initial value other than `a` or `b`), and you never change their values.  Get rid of those one-letter names; they don't help make your code clear.  Also, work through a tutorial on Boolean operations: you've made a common mental slip in your compound condition: you will have a hard time finding a value that will make both conditions `False`.

```
playerInput = input()
while (playerInput != "a") and \
      (playerInput != "b"):
    playerInput = input()
```

Perhaps more "Pythonic" is

```
while not playerInput in ("a", "b"):
    playerInput = input("Please choose 'a' or 'b': ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
playerInput = ""
while (playerInput != "a") and (playerInput != "b"):
    playerInput = input()
```

The main problem is you assign `x` and `y` before the loop.

Comment: This solves one problem, but still leaves an infinite loop.  To exit, the input would have to be both `a` and `b` at the same time.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, but I won't update this answer with the correct code because it'd be just a copy paste from your answer. Your answer is more complete and should be the accepted answer anyways